# JavaScript - Trying to add value to text field by clicking button

Tags: javascript, html

Cant get my function to work and add the value of the button to the text field when clicked by user.

## HTML

```
<form name="testing" action="test.php" method="get">Chords:
<textarea name="field"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="G" onClick="addToField('G');">
<input type="button" value="C" onClick="addToField('C');">
<input type="button" value="Am" onClick="addToField('Am');">
<input type="button" value="F" onClick="addToField('F');">
```

## JavaScript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function addToField(crd){
        document.testing.field.value += crd;
    }
</script>
```

Really stuck trying to understand whats wrong here.

Hope this shows what I am trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/034hyjo2/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSFiddle is way wrong. You're question here is better. You want to be using `document.getElementById('field').value += crd;` instead of `document.testing.field.value += crd;`

try this:

```
<form name="testing" action="test.php" method="get">Chords:
    <textarea id="field" name="field"> </textarea> ---note the addition of the ID parameter
    <input type="button" value="G" onClick="AddToField('G');">
    <input type="button" value="C" onClick="AddToField('C');">
    <input type="button" value="Am" onClick="AddToField('Am');">
    <input type="button" value="F" onClick="AddToField('F');">
</form>

<script>
function AddToField(c) {
    document.getElementById('field').value += c;
};
</script>
```

Also functions shouldn't be camelCase but Pascal case ;)

Comment: Thanks Hugo, big help!

Answer (score 2):

You're accessing the object incorrectly

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function addToField(crd){
        document.getElementByName("testing").value += crd;
    }
</script>
```

Or, give the element an ID and use getElementByID("testing").value.
I usually find that works better anyway...

Answer (score 2):

If you're just getting it in the fiddle, it works by putting the script tag above your HTML:

```
<script>
    var addToField = function(c) {
        document.testing.field.value += c;
    };
</script>
<form name="testing" action="test.php" method="get">Chords:
    <textarea name="field"> </textarea>
    <input type="button" value="G" onClick="addToField('G');">
    <input type="button" value="C" onClick="addToField('C');">
    <input type="button" value="Am" onClick="addToField('Am');">
    <input type="button" value="F" onClick="addToField('F');">
</form>
```